# DRBD/Corosync mysql clutser

Tags: mysql, drbd, corosync

I have configured HA cluster on two nodes host1 and host2. host1 is master and host2 is slave.

If I shutdown host1 then host2 never comes up as master until I restart openais service. Some time I have to restart several times.

If I start Host1 (master again) then it becomes slave of host2 and never comes up as master until I restart service on both nodes.

On both hosts openais service starts on boot.

Please find below my CRM configurations

```
primitive p_drbd_mysql ocf:linbit:drbd params drbd_resource="r0" \
   op monitor interval="15s" ms ms_drbd_mysql p_drbd_mysql \
   meta master-max="1" master-node-max="1" clone-max="2" \
   clone-node-max="1" notify="true"

primitive p_fs_mysql ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem params \
      device="/dev/drbd0" directory=" /var/lib/mysql_drbd" fstype="ext3"

primitive p_ip_mysql ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 params \
      ip="10.40.12.254" cidr_netmask="22" nic="eth0"

primitive p_mysql lsb:mysql
```

Thanks

Mahmood

Comment: Your configuration is missing location and ordering constraints. If this works at all it is purely coincidence. Are you utilizing resource level fencing within the DRBD resource configuration (http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-pacemaker-fencing.html)? If so try disabling it at present for troubleshooting. Other clues may lie in the full *current* configuration "crm configure show" (or it's pcs equivalent), as well as within logs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I have followed M**ySQL High Availability: DRBD
Configuration and Deployment Guide** for configuration.
I have copied all the output of **crm configure show** command. 
Can you please have a look and let me know how can I improve my configurations
Thanks a lot in advance

Mahmood

node clus2
primitive p_drbd_mysql ocf:linbit:drbd \

```
    params drbd_resource="r0" \

    op monitor interval="15s"
```

primitive p_fs_mysql ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem \

```
    params device="/dev/drbd0" directory=" /var/lib/mysql_drbd" fstype="ext3"
```

primitive p_ip_mysql ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \

```
    params ip="10.40.12.254" cidr_netmask="22" nic="eth0"
```

primitive p_mysql lsb:mysql

group g_mysql p_fs_mysql p_ip_mysql p_mysql

ms ms_drbd_mysql p_drbd_mysql \

```
    meta master-max="1" master-node-max="1" clone-max="2" clone-node-max="1"
```

notify="true"
colocation c_mysql_on_drbd inf: g_mysql ms_drbd_mysql:Master
order o_drbd_before_mysql inf: ms_drbd_mysql:promote g_mysql:start
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \

```
    dc-version="1.1.10-f3eeaf4" \

    cluster-infrastructure="classic openais (with plugin)" \

    expected-quorum-votes="2" \

    stonith-enabled="false" \
    no-quorum-policy="ignore"
```

rsc_defaults $id="rsc-options" \
        resource-stickiness="100"